# How to use Anchor's `.view()` in frontend without prompting wallet to sign?

Tags: anchor, anchor-client, solang

Solang currently uses Anchor's `.view()` to fetch account state from the client. The issue is that when using `.view()` in a frontend, it also prompts the wallet to sign a transaction. Is there a way to prevent the connected wallet from being prompted?

```
import { Button } from "@chakra-ui/react"
import { PublicKey } from "@solana/web3.js"
import { useWallet } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react"
import { useProgram } from "@/contexts/ProgramContextProvider"

export default function ViewButton() {
  const { publicKey } = useWallet()
  const { program } = useProgram()

  const onClick = async () => {
    if (!publicKey || !program) return

    const [pda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("seed"), publicKey.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    )

    const val = await program.methods
      .get()
      .accounts({ dataAccount: pda })
      .view()

    alert(val)
  }

  return <Button onClick={onClick}>View</Button>
}
```

The standard way of fetching account data in Anchor using `.fetch` currently isn't supported in Solang due to differences in how the account data is encoded (Solang doesn't use borsh).

```
// Cannot use this approach
const accountData = await program.account.accountType.fetch(address)
```

For additional context, here is the Solang program:

```
@program_id("GwnWG8hjzBBnXRtQAmr3Cbo6ShYjv5s6NHTAdsmURXKa")
contract pda_account {
    bool private value = true;

    @payer(payer) // payer address
    @seed("seed") // hardcoded seed
    @seed(abi.encode(payer)) // seed from payer address
    @bump(bump) // bump seed for pda address
    constructor(address payer, bytes bump) {
        print("Hello, World!");
    }

    /// A message that can be called on instantiated contracts.
    /// This one flips the value of the stored `bool` from `true`
    /// to `false` and vice versa.
    function flip() public {
        value = !value;
    }

    /// Simply returns the current value of our `bool`.
    function get() public view returns (bool) {
        return value;
    }
}
```

The `program` instance was set up using `useAnchorWallet()`

```
const wallet = useAnchorWallet()
   
...

// Set up AnchorProvider using the connected wallet
const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {})
setProvider(provider)

// Program Id from IDL
const programId = IDL.metadata.address as unknown as PublicKey

// Create the program instance using the IDL, program ID, and provider
const program = new Program<PdaAccount>(IDL, programId, provider)
```

Answer (score 2):

Still haven't figured out how to use Anchor's `.view()` in a frontend without it prompting the connected wallet to sign for the simulated transaction.

As a workaround, you can manually build a versioned transaction which does not seem to require a signer when simulating. You can then manually parse out the return data from the program logs of the simulated transaction.

This isn't a great solution, but its an attempt to replicate what [`.view()`](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/ts/packages/anchor/src/program/namespace/views.ts) does.
Also thanks to [SolAndy](https://twitter.com/HeyAndyS) for the recent [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0E2mJljK8I&ab_channel=Solandy%5Bsolandy.sol%5D) on simulating transactions.

```
export default function ViewButton() {
  const { publicKey } = useWallet();
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const { program } = useProgram();

  const onClick = async () => {
    if (!publicKey || !program) return;

    const [pda] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
      [Buffer.from("seed"), publicKey.toBuffer()],
      program.programId
    );

    // Build the instruction
    const ix = await program.methods
      .get()
      .accounts({ dataAccount: pda })
      .instruction();

    const data = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();

    // Build a versioned transaction with the instruction
    const msg = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: data.blockhash,
      instructions: [ix],
    }).compileToV0Message();

    const tx = new VersionedTransaction(msg);

    // Simulate the transaction.
    const transactionSimulation = await connection.simulateTransaction(tx);
    console.log(transactionSimulation);

    // If value is "0", then return data returns null, so can't use this for bool 
    if (transactionSimulation.value.returnData?.data) {
      console.log(transactionSimulation.value.returnData.data[0]);
    }

    // Log all the transaction logs.
    const transactionLogs = transactionSimulation.value.logs;
    console.log(transactionLogs);

    // As workaround to avoid null return data when value is "0"
    // Extract the program return data directly from the logs.
    // Find log entry that starts with "Program return:"
    const returnPrefix = `Program return: ${program.programId} `;
    const returnLogEntry = transactionLogs!.find((log) =>
      log.startsWith(returnPrefix)
    );
    console.log(returnLogEntry);

    if (returnLogEntry) {
      // Slice out the prefix to get the base64 return data
      const encodedReturnData = returnLogEntry.slice(returnPrefix.length);
      console.log(encodedReturnData);

      // Convert the Base64 return data
      const decodedBuffer = Buffer.from(encodedReturnData, "base64");
      alert(decodedBuffer[0]);
    }
  };

  return <Button onClick={onClick}>View</Button>;
```

For additional context, `console.log(transactionLogs);` logs

```
"Program GwnWG8hjzBBnXRtQAmr3Cbo6ShYjv5s6NHTAdsmURXKa invoke [1]"
"Program GwnWG8hjzBBnXRtQAmr3Cbo6ShYjv5s6NHTAdsmURXKa consumed 310 of 200000 compute units"
"Program return: GwnWG8hjzBBnXRtQAmr3Cbo6ShYjv5s6NHTAdsmURXKa AA=="
"Program GwnWG8hjzBBnXRtQAmr3Cbo6ShYjv5s6NHTAdsmURXKa success"
```

`console.log(returnLogEntry);` finds the log with the prefix

```
Program return: GwnWG8hjzBBnXRtQAmr3Cbo6ShYjv5s6NHTAdsmURXKa AA==
```

`console.log(encodedReturnData);` slices out the prefix

```
AA==
```